# Getting Cannot set property of undefined Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, set, setstate

I am new to react and I need your help.

I have shared a sandbox link, In that everything works perfectly. But when we add couple new row(by clicking `+` at rightmost columns of the row) then if we remove some row(by clicking `-` at rightmost columns of the row) and then again add a new row then edit that row cell I am getting `Cannot set property` error. I know I have to do some changes in the `handleDelete` function but not getting what exactly to do. So is anyone experts here, please help me out.
And regarding `Icon` except the last row every other row should have `-` icon.

Thank you. Comment if you need any clarification.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-microservice-qd3ku?file=/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render` method actually passes third argument which is actually an id of your component, in your case you don't recalculate the id and that is why your `dataSource[key]` tries to access key that doesn't exist in dataSource anymore.

```
render: (text, record, id) => (
            <Input
              {/* ... */}
              onChange={e => this.onChange(e, id)}
            />
          )
```

Here I updated your codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-proskuriakova-6f2u0?file=/index.js:1095-1109

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: OK. That was what I am missing. Thanks for the help. :)